# How to dynamically instantiate fullcalendar on buttonclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

basically I want to show different fullcalendars in day-view next to each other. This is some sort of resource-compare-view. A user should be able to select the desired resources from a list on the left and the respective calendar should then be added on the screen.

So, I made a little test and tried to create a fullcalendar-instance by clicking on a simple link. The calendar then shows up for approx. 1 second and the disappears.

This is the code i used to test:

```
<html>
...
<script type='text/javascript'>

$(document).ready(function() 
{
  $("#cmdAddNewDay").click( function() { addNewDayView() } );
});

function addNewDayView()
{
  var cal = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ });    
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='commands'>
    <a href='' id="cmdAddNewDay">Add new cal</a>
</div>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Funny thing is, that when I call addNewDayView from $(document).ready it all works.
What probably fundamental point am I missing here?

Thanks for your help, 
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/j8zvQ/1/

Use event.preventDefault() to prevent the default link behaviour.

```
  $("#cmdAddNewDay").click( function(event) { 
      event.preventDefault();
      addNewDayView() 
  } );
```